# How do I copy multiple files from remote location?

Tags: perl

I'm able to copy a single file from remote location as below:

```
use File::Copy;

$Server="192.168.1.2";
$ServerDir="\\C:\\temp\\test.txt";
my $From = "\\\\".$Server.$ServerDir;

copy("$From","C:\\temp\\local\\") or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

But, when there is more than one file in my $ServerDir(\C:\temp\*.txt), how can I copy them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Loop through each file, then copy one by one like this:

```
use File::Copy;
use File::Glob;

$Server="192.168.1.2";
$ServerDir="\\C:\\temp\\";
$From = "\\\\".$Server.$ServerDir;

my @files = glob("$From\\*.txt");

for my $file (@files) {
    copy("$From\\$file","C:\\temp\\local\\") or die "Copy failed: $!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) in a loop:

```
for (glob 'C:\temp\*.txt') {
    copy($_, "C:\\temp\\local\\") or die "Copy failed: $_ $!";
}
```